# How to calculate running total in sql backwards

Tags: sql, t-sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2pmV.png)

```
select id,date,amount,SUM (Amount)  OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE desc)  AS runningbalance from sales
```

I have tried this to reverse running balance going from the most recent to older records. How can I reverse this to go backwards to give me running balance the other way?

Comment: Should be as simple as changing your `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY DATE` or `ORDER BY DATE ASC`

Answer (score 2):

If your `ID` is unique to each row then remove the `PARTITION BY ID` else it won't sum cumulatively. To reverse the order of the running total simply reverse the `ORDER BY` of the `SUM`:

DDL:

```
declare @sales table (
    ID int,
    Date date,
    Amount int);

insert into @sales
values
    (1, '2020-01-01', 15),
    (2, '2020-01-02', 10),
    (3, '2020-01-03', 5);
```

DML:

```
select ID, Date, Amount, 
    sum(Amount) over (order by Date) as RunningBalanceForward, 
    sum(Amount) over (order by Date desc) as RunningBalanceBackwards
from @sales
order by ID
```

Results:

| ID | Date | Amount | RunningBalanceForward | RunningBalanceBackwards |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 15 | 15 | 30 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 10 | 25 | 15 |
| 3 | 2020-01-03 | 5 | 30 | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the running total, use a row_number to create the sort column and partition it by id order by date desc generating a rowid then order by the rowid

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an example of what the partition is used for.

> ```
> declare @Sales table (
>   ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
>   [Date] date,
>   Store varchar(30),
>   Amount int
>   
> );
>
> insert into @Sales ([Date], Store, Amount)
> values
>   ('2020-01-01','A',1), ('2020-01-03','A',1)
> , ('2020-01-05','A',1)
> , ('2020-01-02','B',10), ('2020-01-04','B',10)
> , ('2020-01-06','B',10)
> ;
>     
> select Store, [Date], Amount, 
>     sum(Amount) over (partition by Store order by [Date] ASC) as RunningTotal, 
>     sum(Amount) over (partition by Store order by [Date] DESC) as ReverseRunningTotal
> from @Sales
> order by Store, [Date] 
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Store | Date       | Amount | RunningTotal | ReverseRunningTotal
> :---- | :--------- | -----: | -----------: | ------------------:
> A     | 2020-01-01 |      1 |            1 |                   3
> A     | 2020-01-03 |      1 |            2 |                   2
> A     | 2020-01-05 |      1 |            3 |                   1
> B     | 2020-01-02 |     10 |           10 |                  30
> B     | 2020-01-04 |     10 |           20 |                  20
> B     | 2020-01-06 |     10 |           30 |                  10
> ```